# Sort linked list by using Quick sort in python

Tags: python, linked-list, quicksort

I'm new to python. I have the following list of books stored on the linked list and I want to sort them by using quicksort but unfortunately, I'm stuck on a problem.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data=None):
        self.data = data
        self.prev = None
        self.next = None


class DoublyLinkedList:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head = None
        self.tail = None

    def append_value(self, x):
        if not isinstance(x, Node):
            x = Node(x)
        if self.is_empty():
            self.head = x
        else:
            current = self.head
            while current.next:
                current = current.next
            current.next = x
            x.prev = current
        self.tail = x

    def length(self):
        count = 0
        current = self.head
        while current:
            count += 1
            current = current.next
        return count

    def is_empty(self):
        return self.head is None

    def __str__(self):
        to_print = ''
        current = self.head
        while current:
            to_print += f'{current.data} <-> '
            current = current.next
        if to_print:
            return f'[{to_print[:-5]}]'
        return '[]'

    def quick_sort(self, arr):
        if self.length() < 2:
            return self
        else:
            pivot = self.tail.data
            smaller, equal, larger = [], [], []
            current = self.head
            while current:
                if current.data < pivot:
                    smaller.append(current.data)
                elif current.data == pivot:
                    equal.append(current.data)
                else:
                    larger.append(current.data)
                current = current.next
        return self.quick_sort(smaller) + equal + self.quick_sort(larger)
```

This is the quicksort method but it's giving me RecursionError on 'return self.quick_sort(smaller) + equal + self.quick_sort(larger)'. How do I sort the linked list by using quicksort?

```
my_list = DoublyLinkedList()
my_list.append_value('In Search of Lost Time')
my_list.append_value('Ulysses by James Joyce')
my_list.append_value('Within a Budding Grove')
my_list.append_value('The Guermantes Way')
my_list.append_value('In Search of Lost Time')
my_list.append_value('Sodom & Gomorrah')
my_list.append_value('One Hundred Years of Solitude')
my_list.append_value('War and Peace')

print(f'List of Books: {my_list}')

print(f'Quick Sort: {my_list.quick_sort(my_list)}')
```

Comment: Step 1 is to debug your program, using a GUI debugger, and step through the code line-by-line to see where the execution differs from your expectations. It sounds like you haven't debugged this in that way.

Comment: [How to debug small programs.](//ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)
|
[What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](//stackoverflow.com/q/25385173/843953) | Create a [mre], then ask a _specific_ question. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask], and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to SO!

Comment: I tried debugging the code. But that didn't solve the problem.

Comment: The problem is here when I do this:
smaller, equal, larger = [], [], []
A linked list is not accepting <class 'list'>. I think I have to convert that into <class '__main__.Node'>, but I'm not able to do so (trying debugging could not solve the problem).

Thanks.

Comment: Side note: it feels somewhat like cheating that you copy values from the linked list into standard lists: every value gets appended to a list at some point. If you do that, you may wonder why you don't copy the the linked list completely in a list, sort that list, and create the linked list from that. If this is an assignment, then I cannot imagine that standard lists are supposed to be used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Indeed, the error occurs because you pass a standard list to `quick_sort`, while it expects the argument to be a doubly linked list instance.

Moreover, it would be strange if the use of lists were allowed in this algorithm, as then one may wonder why there is a doubly linked list in the first place. If you're going to use lists, then you might as well store the data in a list and sort the list. This cannot be the purpose.

Some other comments about the code:

- `quick_sort` is a method of the class, so it should not be necessary to pass the linked list *also* as argument. Instead, pass two arguments that identify the start and end node of a subsection in that linked list.
- The final `return` statement is problematic. If indeed `quick_sort` is going to return a linked list, then `+` is not an operator you can use on those. Moreover, Quick Sort is supposed to be an *in-place* sorting algorithm, while `+` suggests a new list being created. As it is in-place, you should be able to just return `self`.

So, ... you really need to solve this by walking through the linked list and manipulate it.

Here is one way to do it. First define two methods that allow inserting and deleting a node anywhere in the list:

```
def remove_node(self, node):
    if node.prev:
        node.prev.next = node.next
    else:
        self.head = node.next
    if node.next:
        node.next.prev = node.prev
    else:
        self.tail = node.prev
    node.next = node.prev = None
    return node

def insert_after(self, prev, node):
    if not isinstance(node, Node):
        node = Node(node)
    node.prev = prev
    if prev:
        node.next = prev.next
        prev.next = node
    else:
        node.next = self.head
        self.head = node
    if node.next:
        node.next.prev = node
    else:
        self.tail = node
    return self
```

The latter is in fact a more flexible method than the `append_value` you already had. You could actually make use of this new one to define yours:

```
def append_value(self, x):
    return self.insert_after(self.tail, x)
```

Then perform the quick sort as follows:

Take a start and end node as arguments. Extract (remove) the end node from the list and consider it the pivot. Let two references walk along this sublist towards each other, starting at the ends. When their values are at the good side of the pivot value, let that reference move closer. Once you have two references where the value is opposite from the pivot, swap the data that is in these two nodes. Once these two references cross each other you have identified the two partitions. Inject the pivot node back into the list, right between those two partitions. Finally, use recursion to do the same with the two partitions:

```
def quick_sort(self, start=None, end=None):
    if not start and not end:  # set default arguments:
        start = self.head
        end = self.tail
    if not start or not end or start == end or end.next == start:
        # The sublist is empty or has just one value
        return self
    # Extract the pivot node from the list
    end, pivot = end.prev, self.remove_node(end)
    pivotdata = pivot.data
    # Define two references that will walk towards eachother:
    right = end
    left = start
    while left and left.prev != right:  # While they didn't cross over
        if left.data <= pivotdata:
            left = left.next
        elif right.data >= pivotdata:
            right = right.prev
        else: # Swap values, not the nodes:
            left.data, right.data = right.data, left.data
            left = left.next
            right = right.prev
        
    # Insert the pivot node between the two partitions
    self.insert_after(right, pivot)
    # Sort the non-empty partitions recursively
    if start.prev != pivot:
        self.quick_sort(start, right)
    if end.next != pivot:
        self.quick_sort(left, end)
    return self
```

Comment: Your answer helped. Tell me more about 'while left and left.prev != right:'. Didn't get it?

I think you're moving both left and right pointer one by one till both are not equal (a left pointer towards next and a right one towards previous). And, as soon as the left node becomes equal to the right node, swap the values of the nodes. Is this what you did right?

Comment: Also, what does this thing do?

        if end.next == pivot:
            end = pivot
        if start.prev == pivot:
            start = pivot

Comment: The process of moving `left` and `right` is like in standard Quick Sort (on an array). They start at the extreme ends of the sublist and then move towards eachother until they *overtake* eachother. So when the loop ends, `right` is at the left of `left` (or they become `None` when they drop of the list).

Comment: As to your second question: that deals with a boundary case which occurs when the pivot happens to be smaller (or greater) than *all* values in the sublist. In that case we re-insert the pivot *next* to the sublist (either just before `start` or just after `end`). If that happens, there is only one partition to process in a recursive call. Note that you quoted a version of the code that I updated later. It wasn't wrong, but I like it better this way.